# unable to return the $.posted php file data back in a jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

This is my custom jQuery function:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.NotYet = function(arti_id) {
        this.append(function() {
            var result = 0;
            $.post("comment_load.php", {arti_id:arti_id, status:1}, function(data){
                console.log(data);          // Returns data from POSTed PHP file
                console.log(result);        // Returns 0
                //$(this).append(result);   // Not Working
                result = data;
                console.log(result);        // Returns data from POSTed PHP file
            });
            console.log(result);            // Returns 0
            return result;                  // Returns 0
        });         
        return this;                        // Returns 0
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
$("div#Comments").NotYet(15);
```

I am trying to make a jQuery function, but I am unable to return the posted php file data back to into the `<div>` container.

Any suggestions?

FYI: This question is similar, but I could not understand what is happening and I needed a simple method. [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `$.post` is async.

Comment: `console.log(result); return result;`: this part possibly executed before the AJAX finish.

Comment: Please share your PHP[comment_load.php code here

Comment: You are trying to eat a pizza before it gets delivered

Comment: Nice one. :D @charlietfl

Comment: @Eddie sometimes non technical jargon sinks in quicker...take that pizza out of their mouths and they think fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.post`  is async method its cant return anything. And your problem is result value set before ajax call end.That why  the console.log value as `0`.

1. so you need to set inside the callback of success function.
2. And inside the call back `this` element as invalid one.So you need declare some another variable before pass to the success function like `var that = this`

**Code**:

```
(function($) {
      $.fn.NotYet = function(arti_id) {
        this.append(function() {
         var that = this;
          var result = 0;
          $.post("comment_load.php", {
            arti_id: arti_id,
            status: 1
          }, function(data) {
            console.log(data); // Returns data from POSTed PHP file

            $(that).append(data);   //its work
            result = data;

          });
          console.log(result); // Returns 0 //its excute before ajax call
          return result; // its not possible
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: That Worked Thanks @prasanth

Comment: @Ramyz. you are always welcome